# Fill out a group table with 6 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ be a group whose table is partially shown below:

\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
            * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
            \hline
            0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &    &  \\
            \hline
            2 &  2 &    &    &   &     & \\
            \hline
            3 & 3  & 5  &  &   &  & 1\\
            \hline
            4 & 4  &    &  &   &  &  \\
            \hline
            5 &  5 &   &  &   & & \\
            \hline
        \end{array}

> *Complete the table.*

---

Needed to use Inverses, cancellation and No 1 element can repeat per row/col, but got the wrong table.

\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
            * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
            \hline
            0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            \hline
            1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &  5   & 3 \\
            \hline
            2 &  2 &  0  & 1   & 5  &  3   & 4 \\
            \hline
            3 & 3  & 5  & 4  & 2  & 0 & 1\\
            \hline
            4 & 4  &  3  & 5 & 0  & 1 & 2 \\
            \hline
            5 &  5 & 4  & 3 & 1  & 2& 0\\
            \hline
        \end{array}

What is the correct table?

Comment: The group has five or six elements?

Comment: i dont counts zero, ups it has six. ill edit it

Comment: was told that the block 3x3 on the lower right with $0,1,2$ is incorrect

Comment: What you have tells you $1*3\neq 3*1$ so you are definitely nonabelian. There is just one possible group, and that has three elements of order $2$.

Comment: You also need to use the most important group property of all, the *associative law*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing it is isomorphic to the dihedral group on $6 $ elements. You have gone wrong in the last "quater" of the grid.

\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &  5   & 3 \\ 
   \hline
   2 &  2 &  0  & 1   & 5  &  3   & 4 \\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  & 4  & \color{red}{0}  & \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{1}\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &  3  & 5 & \color{blue}{1}  & \color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{2} \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 & 4  & 3 & \color{blue}{2}  & \color{blue}{1}& \color{red}{0}\\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}

$D_6 = \{ e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b \mid a^3=b^2=e \, \, \,  ab=ba^2 \}$ The elements $\color{red}{b,ab \text{ and } a^2 b}$ are of order $\color{red}{2}$.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without "guessing".  As $1*1=2$ and $1*2=1^3=0$ we know we have $\{e,a,a^2|a^3\}$.  Can we deduce the rest?

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you had got this far and needed to fill out the rest:

\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &  5   & 3 \\ 
   \hline
   2 &  2 &  0  & 1   & 5  &  3   & 4 \\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  & 4 & ? \\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &  3  & 5  \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 & 4  & 3 \\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}

One way to proceed would be to use the property of *associativity*, which says that $(ab)c = a(bc)$. Let $a = 3^2$, and consider $3^3$: since $(3^2)3 = 3(3^2)$, we have $a\cdot3=3\cdot a$. In other words, $3$ and $a$ commute, and since $a \in \{0,1,2\}$, we see that $a=0$.

It's important to understand that the group multiplication table has more properties than just containing a permutation of the elements in each row and column; otherwise you merely have a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Answer (score 6):

Let's take it slow

$\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &    &  \\ 
   \hline
   2 &  2 &    &    &   &     & \\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  &  &   &  & 1\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &    &  &   &  &  \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 &   &  &   & & \\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}$

As each row and column must be distinct we can start by "soduku"ing the $1*a$ row.

$\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &  \color{blue}5  & \color{blue}3 \\ 
   \hline
   2 &  2 &    &    &   &     & \\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  &  &   &  & 1\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &    &  &   &  &  \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 &   &  &   & & \\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}$

Now $1*2=0$ so $2=-1$ So if we replace $2$ with $-1$ and use $\pm 1*m=k\iff m=\pm 1* k$ and $k*\pm 1=m \iff k=m*\mp 1$ we can get the following ($\color{green}{green}$ for $1/-1$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$ for "sudoku"ing):

$\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & -1 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & -1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 4 &  \color{blue}5  & \color{blue}3 \\ 
   \hline
   -1 &  -1 &  \color{green}0  &  \color{green} 1  &  \color{green}5 & \color{green}3    & \color{green}4\\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  & \color{green}4 &   &  & 1\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &  \color{blue}3  & \color{green}5 &   &  &  \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 & \color{blue}4  & \color{green}3 &   & & \\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}$

Now $3*5 = 1$ so $3*5*-1 = 0$ and $3*3=0$

And knowing $a*b = a*0*b = (a*1)(-1*b)=(a*-1)(1*b)$ we see:  $3*3= 4*1*-1*4=4*4;3*3=5*-1*1*5=5*5=0$.

$\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & -1 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & -1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 4 &  \color{blue}5  & \color{blue}3 \\ 
   \hline
   -1 &  -1 &  \color{green}0  &  \color{green} 1  &  \color{green}5 & \color{green}3    & \color{green}4\\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  & \color{green}4 & \color{red}0  &  & 1\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &  \color{blue}3  & \color{green}5 &   & \color{red}0 &  \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 & \color{blue}4  & \color{green}3 &   & & \color{red}0\\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}$

We can "sudoku" the rest (and replace $-1$ with $2$)

$\begin{array}{ c| c | c | c | c |c|c|}
   * & 0& 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 &  \color{blue}5  & \color{blue}3 \\ 
   \hline
   2 &  2 &  \color{green}0  &  \color{green} 1  &  \color{green}5 & \color{green}3    & \color{green}4\\ 
   \hline
   3 & 3  & 5  & \color{green}4 & \color{red}0  & \color{blue}2 & 1\\ 
   \hline
   4 & 4  &  \color{blue}3  & \color{green}5 & \color{blue}1  & \color{red}0 & \color{blue}2 \\ 
   \hline
   5 &  5 & \color{blue}4  & \color{green}3 & \color{blue}2  & \color{blue}1& \color{red}0\\ 
   \hline
  \end{array}$

Hmm, though actually we haven't verified that what we were given would be a group.  We just took it on faith.  But we can verify by associativity it holds.

====

Here's an expansion and David Splutterwit's answer.  This is hopefully not such a haphazard guessing game and hopefully will unquestionably be a group.

First, let's not use numbers, that confusing.

Let's use $e=0,a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,g=5$.($e$ is the identity.)

We know $a^2 = b$ $(1*1=2)$ and $a*b = a*a^2 = a^3=0$ $(1*2 = 0)$

So we have $\{e,a, a^2, c,d,g\}$

We have the three following relations: $a*c=d$, $c*a=g$, and $c*g=c^2a=a$.  Which would therefore mean $c^2 = e$

So we have $\{e,a,a^2,c,ac,ca|a^3 = c^2= e\}$. $ac\ne ca$.

Now $a*e = a, a*a= a^2, a*a^2 = e, a*c = ac$ and $a*ac\ne ac$.  So $a*ac = ca$

So we have $\{e, a, a^2, c,ac,a^2c|a^3=c^2=e, a^2c = ca\}$.

And that's enough to describe a group.

Or $\{0, 1, 1^2=2, 3, 1*3=4, 1^23=5|1^3=3^2=0, 1^23=3*1\}$.

You can fill in the table from there.

Wish I had thought of that first.  It's much more "grown-up" than filling in a table.

Comment: By a haphazard computation of my own, it seems like you actually need to "sudoku" the first row as you did, otherwise you get a group of order 216, even if you assume lots (all?) of the elements have order dividing 6.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  As we are told that there are 6 elements we had not choice.  Do you mean if we figured $1*4\ne 5$ and we can add 6,7,8,9, as necessary we'd need 216?  I'll take you word for it.  Is that true if we let $1*4 =3$ or $1*5 = 3$ or $4$?

Comment: I meant to say that I was using "assume everything is of order 6" as a stand-in for "assume the group has exactly 6 elements."  I wanted to see if the presentation of the group that comes from reading off filled-in elements of the multiplication table would work, but it ends up being a group with 216 elements that surjects onto this particular group.  Just found it interesting.  Just adding $1*4=5$ or $1*5=3$ without the "everything is order 6" constraint is enough to get a group of order 6.